# Formal args of purrr partially applied function

Tags: r, purrr

I want to get to a functional interface in my user-facing functions, but I am struggling with how partially applied functions work (defined using the `purrr` package). Partially applied functions seem to be just wrapped inside of a function that has an `...` formal argument list:

```
> a <- function(x=2,y=2) {return(list(x,y))}
> b <- purrr::partial(a,x=3)
> b(3)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 3

> formals(b)
$...
```

But for my code I need to get the *true* formal arguments of the function when partially applied. So, the result of the final line should be something like this:

```
> formals(b)
$y
[1] 2
```

Is there any way to get a function that works as a normal one out of a partially applied function?

Comment: There’s no way using ‘purr’, and [from experience](https://github.com/klmr/fun/blob/898148c5b89bccc10ccadf960b81fab0543e97af/__init__.r#L22-L134) I can say that writing a `partial` implementation that’s (a) robust and maintainable, (b) efficient and (c) provides “proper” formal arguments is a pain in the neck, and that’s probably the reason why `purrr::partial` does not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** One approach is to use the CRAN curry package.

```
library(curry)

a <- function(x = 2, y = 2) list(x, y)
b <- curry(a, arg = list(x = 3))

formals(b)
## $y
## [1] 2

args(b)
## function (y = 2) 
## NULL
```

**2)** Another approach is to change the defaults.  The CRAN default package and the github alrtools packages take this approach.

```
library(default)

a <- function(x = 2, y = 2) list(x, y)
b <- a
default(b) <- list(x = 3)

formals(b)
## $x
## [1] 3
##
## $y
## [1] 2

args(b)
## function (x = 3, y = 2) 
## NULL

########################################################

# remotes::install_github("adamleerich/alrtools")

library(alrtools)

a <- function(x=2,y=2) {return(list(x,y))}
b <- curry(a, x = 3)

formals(b)
## $x
## [1] 3
##
## $y
## [1] 2

args(b)
## function (x = 3, y = 2) 
## NULL
```